# Custom Map Collector

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I have a collection constisting of `Map<Pair<DateTime, String>, List<Entity>>` which was previously grouped using streams. `Entity` is a simple class with `int` property and `getValue()` method.

Now, I want to aggregate values of `Entity` with usage of my simple `EntityAccumulator` modyfing the type of the previous map to `Map<Pair<DateTime, String>, EntityAccumulator>`. The only way to achieve this as far as I understand is to create my own custom collector, howevere I've stucked at `finisher()` method which should return `Pair`.

Or, maybe is there simpler way to achieve the result I want ?

**StreamProcessing**

```
 Map<Pair<DateTime, String>, EntityAccumulator> collect = entities.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(entity-> Pair.of(entity.getTimestamp(), entity.getName())))
                .entrySet().stream()
                .collect(new EntityCollector()));
```

**EntityAccumulator**

```
private static class EntityAccumulator {

        private int result = 0.0;

        public EntityAccumulator() { }

        public EntityAccumulator(int result) {
            this.result = result;
        }

        public void calculate(Entity entity) {
            result += entity.getValue();
        }

        public EntityAccumulatoradd(EntityAccumulator other) {
            return new EntityAccumulator(this.result + other.result);
        }
}
```

**Collector**

```
public class EntityCollector implements Collector<Map.Entry<Pair<DateTime, String>, List<Entity>>, EntityAccumulator, Map.Entry<Pair<DateTime, String>, EntityAccumulator>> {

    @Override
    public Supplier<EntityAccumulator> supplier() {
        return EntityAccumulator::new;
    }

    @Override
    public BiConsumer<EntityAccumulator, Map.Entry<Pair<DateTime, String>, List<Entity>>> accumulator() {
        return (result, pairListEntry) -> pairListEntry.getValue().forEach(result::calculate);
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<EntityAccumulator> combiner() {
        return EntityAccumulator::add;
    }

    @Override
    public Function<EntityAccumulator, Map.Entry<Pair<DateTime, String>, EntityAccumulator>> finisher() {
        return (k) -> {
            return  null; // ??? HELP HERE 
        }
    }


    @Override
    public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
        return EnumSet.of(Characteristics.UNORDERED);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently, you actually want to do

```
Map<Pair<DateTime, String>, Double> collect = entities.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        entity -> Pair.of(entity.getTimestamp(), entity.getName()),
        Collectors.summingDouble(Entity::getValue)));
```

or

```
Map<Pair<DateTime, String>, Integer> collect = entities.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        entity -> Pair.of(entity.getTimestamp(), entity.getName()),
        Collectors.summingInt(Entity::getValue)));
```

depending on the actual value type. Your declaration `int result = 0.0` isn’t quite clear.

First, if you want to perform reduction on the groups, you should provide the `Collector` for the values as a second argument to the [`groupingBy` collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-). Then, it doesn’t have to deal with neither, `Map` nor `Map.Entry`.

Since it’s basically folding the entities to a single number (for each group), you can use an existing collector, i.e. [`summingInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) or [`summingDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summingDouble-java.util.function.ToDoubleFunction-).

When you create your own collector, you can’t reconstitute information in the finisher function that you have dropped in the accumulator function. If your container type `EntityAccumulator` contains a single number only, there is no way to produce a `Map.Entry<Pair<DateTime, String>, EntityAccumulator>` from it.

By the way, you rarely need to implemented the `Collector` interface with a class, even when creating a custom collector. You can simply use [`Collector.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html#of-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics...-), specifying the functions and characteristics, to create a `Collector`.

So using your original `EntityAccumulator` class (assuming, `result` should be `int` and `0.0` is a typo), you could use

```
Map<Pair<DateTime, String>, Integer> collect = entities.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        entity -> Pair.of(entity.getTimestamp(), entity.getName()),
        Collector.of(EntityAccumulator::new,
                     EntityAccumulator::calculate,
                     EntityAccumulator::add,
                     ea -> ea.result,
                     Collector.Characteristics.UNORDERED)));
```

to achieve the same as above. It would also be possible to perform the operation in two steps, like in your attempt, using

```
Map<Pair<DateTime, String>, Integer> collect = entities.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> Pair.of(e.getTimestamp(), e.getName())))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().stream().collect(
        Collector.of(EntityAccumulator::new,
                     EntityAccumulator::calculate,
                     EntityAccumulator::add,
                     ea -> ea.result,
                     Collector.Characteristics.UNORDERED))));
```

but, of course, this is only for completeness. The solution shown at the beginning of this answer is simpler and more efficient.

Comment: Thank you, that was helpfull, however in our real app, the `EntityAccumulator` contains three values,`calculate` method has some logic based on other properties and adds to one of them. Is it somehow possible to do similar way as you showed ?

Comment: Well, you can use the custom collector as shown in the answer and simply omit the finisher function to get `EntityAccumulator` values instead of a numbers, i.e. `Map<Pair<DateTime, String>, EntityAccumulator> collect = entities.stream() .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(entity -> Pair.of(entity.getTimestamp(), entity.getName()), Collector.of(EntityAccumulator::new, EntityAccumulator::calculate,EntityAccumulator::add,Collector.Characteristics.UNORDERED)));`. Or use a finisher function that maps to a final result type.

Comment: Oh... yes, that should work. It became a bit confusing after sitting on it for few hours :P. Thank you again